# Adding combinations of rows to columns

Tags: r, matrix

I have 17 square matrices of order 430 and a large matrix of dimension 92235 x 34

1. For each square matrix, I wish to add each row's value (from 1 to 430) to a column in the large matrix, taking only those values above the main diagonal. So [1,2][1,3][1,4]..[1,430][2,3][2,4]...[2,430]...[429,430] -- hence, the 92235 row length of the large matrix (A sample of Step 1 is shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwYuG.jpg)
2. The square matrix is transposed
3. Step 1 is repeated but the row values are added to the next column in the large matrix
4. Repeat Steps 1-3 16 more times until the large matrix is filled

How do I go about doing this?

TIA

**EDIT FOR COMMENT**

```
mat = matrix(1:25,5,5)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

mat2 = cbind(mat[upper.tri(mat)])
mat2
      [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]   11
[3,]   12
[4,]   16
[5,]   17
[6,]   18
[7,]   21
[8,]   22
[9,]   23
[10,]  24
```

This reads columns then rows. Instead, I would like to read rows then columns so that the result should be:

```
      [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]   11
[3,]   16
[4,]   21
[5,]   12
[6,]   17
[7,]   22
[8,]   18
[9,]   23
[10,]  24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 17 square matrices ('m1', 'm2',...'m17'), keep them in a `list` and then use `upper.tri` to extract the elements above the diagonal and `cbind` with the elements from the `transpose`

```
 lst1 <- mget(paste0('m', 1:17))
 Out <- do.call(cbind,lapply(lst1, function(x) {x1 <- t(x)
                   cbind(x[upper.tri(x)], x1[upper.tri(x1)]) }))
 dim(Out)
#[1] 92235    34
```

Here I created the matrices in a list.

#### Update

Based on the row order of the data,

```
mat1 <- mat
mat1[lower.tri(mat1, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
as.vector(na.omit(unlist(tapply(mat1, row(mat1), FUN=I))))
#[1]  6 11 16 21 12 17 22 18 23 24
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments

```
temp <- t(mat)
temp[lower.tri(temp)]
#[1]  6 11 16 21 12 17 22 18 23 24
```

You can replace the steps as here in the `lapply`.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
lst1 <- replicate(17, matrix(sample(1:200, 430*430, replace=TRUE), 
    430, 430), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is great! But it seems like binding x[upper.tri(x)] to the columns of the large matrix reads [1,2][1,3][2,3][1,4][2,4][3,4]... so columns first then rows. How do I read it rows first then columns, so [1,2][1,3][1,4]..[1,430][2,3][2,4]..[2,430]..?

Comment: @pophahpop Please update your post with a small data (as showed in the comments) and the expected result based on that.  I didn't understand your comment

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think it should go as a separate answer, right?